# Change Local Variable in a Function within a Function

Tags: javascript

I have a function where I receive a value, and according to that value I do another `for` procedure inside the function. The `for` loop is different, but the procedure inside is the same. I want to call a function inside the `for` that would afterwards change a local variable in the first function. An example would be:

```
// option = 1 to get first prime number from 1-100, 2 to get the last

function GetPrimeNumber(option){
  var number;

  if(option == 1){
    for(i=1; i < 101; i++){ 
      DetermineIfPrime(i);   
    }    
  }
  else if (option == 2){
    for(i=100; i > 0; i--){ 
      DetermineIfPrime(i);
    }
  }
}
```

And afterwards have my function that determines if the number

```
function DetermineIfPrime(a){

 //Procedure

  if (a == prime){
    number = a;
    break;
  }   
}
```

Is there a way to return values such as what would be `a` to `number` or `break` to the previous function?

Comment: *"Is there a way to return values..."* Yes, yes there is.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to `return` values from functions…

Comment: I recommend to read the [**MDN JavaScript Guide about functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Comment: You cannot affect a variable that is scoped off with the keyword `var` inside another function from within the function you are in. Use a Constructor or Object instead. Note: You could use a return value in your `function DetermineIfPrime(){}`, assigning `number = DetermineIfPrime(i)` inside `GetPrimeNumber()`, but I'm not seeing that it makes sense, since `number` would be the last assignment in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` from `DetermineIfPrime` and set that returned value to `number` like this:

```
function GetPrimeNumber(option){
  var number;

  if (option == 1) {
    for(i=1; i < 101; i++) { 
      number = DetermineIfPrime(i);   
    }    
  } else if (option == 2) {
    for (i=100; i > 0; i--) { 
      number = DetermineIfPrime(i);
    }
  }
}

function DetermineIfPrime(a){

  //Procedure

  if (a == prime){
    return a;
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

number is local to your GetPrimeNumber function so if you want the DetermineIfPrime function to be able to "see" it, you need to define it inside GetPrimerNumber.

That's not the way to go though, you should be returning the value from your function and assigning that to your local var.